# Safely update SKU from DB Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, database, sql, sku

In a store of mine, built on **Magento 2.1.x** I need to perform a bulk update on product **SKUs**.

I am thinking about doing an UPDATE directly on the DB, on the `catalog_product_entity` table, since I noticed that the **SKU** information is stored in this table.

Is it safe doing it? The **SKU** information is contained in other tables?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use SQL instead of Magento API? Have a look here: https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/

Answer (score 2):

You can check which tables have a column with `sku` name using the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%sku%'
```

The result should look like this:

[image: All columns with sku column]

Then you can safely update the `sku` in all tables, but be careful - some columns can have foreign keys. You can disable the foreign key check before the update, and enable it back after:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
# make some changes here ...
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

or manually check all tables before the update.

---

**Note:** this solution will affect only columns which potentially store a `sku`, but Magento has some columns, like `conditions_serialized` where product SKU can be used, where you should make changes manually.

Here is an example from the Shipping Suite module, where SKU used in the `conditions_serialized` column:

[image: example from the Shipping Suite module]

To obtain a list of potentially affected columns you can use these queries:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%serializ%' ORDER BY `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` DESC
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%cond%' ORDER BY `COLUMNS`.`TABLE_SCHEMA` DESC
```

Where `'%serializ%'` means part of the word `serialized`, '%cond%' - part of the word `conditions`.

Example result:

[image: Result for the conditions]

[image: Result for the serialized]

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is what I've been looking for. especially SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '% sku%'. very useful and make it easier to find the column or data you want